# How to resolve a JIRA issue from GitHub commit messages?

Tags: github, jira

I have configured the JIRA bug tracking system with GitHub DVCS. But when I commit the task with message of JIRA key and resolve status, it does not change the status as resolved in JIRA. Is there any command to change the bug status in JIRA from GitHub commit message?

Answer (score 12):

Here is what you need to do to enable 'smart commits':

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Enabling+DVCS+smart+commits

Then, the syntax to use in the commit messages:

`<ISSUE_KEY> #<CMD> <optional CMD_PARAMETERS>`

Example:

```
JRA-123 #resolve
```

More info on the syntax here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages

Comment: In order to be able to do #resolve, should I have a Resolve transition on workflow? Is it not  a workflow state command?

Comment: Yes, #resolve has to be a 'Transition' in your workflow. It is not the state, but the transition which needs to be supplied to smart commits. 

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/processing-jira-software-issues-with-smart-commit-messages-298979931.html explains it in more detail.